# Devices connected to ViewSonic monitor USB KVM switch in power-off state after input change in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, usb, archlinux, multiple-monitors, udev

ViewSonic VP2785-4K monitor has built-in KVM (keyboard/video/mouse) switch using Realtek RTS5411 USB hub. Basically when video input is changed USB devices are reconnected to another computer allowing to use one set of peripherials for many machines.

I've noticed that **under Arch Linux when monitor is connected by upstream USB port peripherial devices are not powered on properly** if:

- monitor was turned off then on
- video input was switched to another machine and back

The hacky way to power on the devices was to rescan USB tree either by invoking `sudo lsusb -v` or `cat /dev/bus/usb/xxx/yyy` (these numbers are machine specific) using directly connected keyboard. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out cause of this annoying behavior and I've found proper solution, so I'm writing this post in Q&A style for all lost Linux souls and for my future self.

Answer (score 1):

The direct reason is that this monitor (and probably whole ViewSonic KVM monitor lineup) does not play well with USB auto power. To fix this:

**Step 1**: Install `usbutils`, you will need it to get device IDs.

**Step 2**: Invoke `lsusb.py`.

**Step 3**: Find USB connection chain in output. For example I know I have Razer mouse connected to my monitor so I'm interested in this branch:

```
usb3              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:73:00.4) hub
  3-1               05e3:0610 09 1IF  [USB 2.10,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (GenesysLogic USB2.1 Hub) hub
    3-1.1             0bda:5411 09 1IF  [USB 2.10,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub) hub
      3-1.1.2           05ac:1006 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps, 300mA] (Apple, Inc. Keyboard Hub 000000000000) hub
        3-1.1.2.2         05ac:0220 00 2IFs [USB 2.00,   1.5 Mbps,  20mA] (Apple, Inc Apple Keyboard)
      3-1.1.3           1532:0060 00 3IFs [USB 2.00,    12 Mbps, 500mA] (Razer Razer Lancehead Tournament Edition)
      3-1.1.4           0bda:5440 11 1IF  [USB 2.01,    12 Mbps,   0mA] (Realtek BillBoard Device 123456789ABCDEFGH)
```

It means that my monitor `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub` is connected to laptop built in `GenesysLogic USB2.1 Hub` which has device index `3-1`, idVendor `05e3` and idProduct `0610`.

**Step 4**: Check current USB port power management: `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/control` (remember to use proper device index) and by default it should print `auto`.

**Step 5**: Modify udev rules to override power behavior. Create as root file `/etc/udev/rules.d/61-autosuspend.rules` with content (remeber to use proper idVendor and idProduct):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{idVendor}=="05e3", ATTR{idProduct}=="0610", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```

This will be executed after stock `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-autosuspend.rules` and will correct power mode for USB port that I use to connect my monitor.

**Step 6 (optional)**: You can test rule before rebooting (remember to use proper device index):

```
udevadm control --reload
udevadm test /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1
```

This will spit out wall of text but you should spot `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-autosuspend.rule` and your new `/etc/udev/rules.d/61-autosuspend.rules`. In this order.

**Step 7**: Reboot. Now if you `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/control` (remember to use proper device index) it should print `on` instead of `auto`. And all devices connected to monitor hub should have power after video input change.

Comment: BTW: Huge kudos to Arch Linux documentation authors. It is really excellent and I would not figure out the solution without it.